Safari bug when trying to set value to a select element
i have a form but when i try to set dynamically a value to a select element safari ignores my value and automatically selects the first element of the select field.
my code works perfectly fine on other browsers but not on safari :
this is a quick sum up of my code :
$('#element').on('change', function() {
    $('#selectElement').val('singapore').change();
});

if anyone may have any insight about might be causing the probleme in symfony please let me know.
Thank you.
we have an address field that's linked to google places api's and should return the country, city, postal code....etc
the expected behaviour is to set the country to the select element ( example : 'singapore' ) but instead when i try to check the actual value of the select element it return 'Afghanistan' ( first element of the select field ).
this probleme is only in safari ( other browsers work perfectly ).
Thanks
